# Is there a DRY way to do error handling in callbacks?

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, boost-asio

I have a networking library that uses asio to do asynchronous reads and writes. I am finding myself writing what I feel is a lot silly boilerplate code:

```
asio::dispatch(m_strand, [&, cb]() {
          m_buffer = write::startup(m_params);
          write(m_buffer, [&, cb](std::error_code ec, std::size_t len) {
            if (ec) {
              sql_state state;
              cb(ec, state);
              return;
            }
            read([&](std::error_code ec, packet barray) {
              if (ec) {
                sql_state state;
                cb(ec, state);
                return;
              }
              auto packets = parse::split_into_packets(barray);
              uint8_t auth_type{1};
              state = fsm::authentication_request(packets.front(), auth_type);
              if (state) {
                cb(ec, std::move(state));
                return;
              }
            });
          });
        });
```

Is there a way to abstract away the error handling in an elegant way?

Comment: Put repeated parts of the code into separate functions.  By nesting use of lambdas or function objects (e.g. lambda creating a lambda, and passing it to another function) - as you are - you are effectively begging to have to rewrite the code every time you use it.   That means, if you do it more than once, repeating the code.

Comment: I'll have less boilerplate but it will still be there.

Comment: Sometimes, that's the way it goes.   Without knowing all the ways in which you repeat this type of code (which is not possible, since you've only provided one example) it's hard to know how to eliminate or reduce repetition in a way that satisfies you.     But you can certainly reduce it by breaking it into smaller functions - templated functions if necessary, since that you are using templated functions (it's not possible to pass lambdas directly to non-templated functions).

Comment: You can try to adapt a solution based on the monadic error handling principle to abstract from your repeated error handling cases: 
[monadic error handling](https://medium.com/@huund/monadic-error-handling-1e2ce66e3810)

This one uses boost optionals but you can achieve the same goal with the std optional from c++17: 
[c++ friendly version](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/07/04/multiple-error-handling-with-the-optional-monad-in-c/)

Comment: If you can afford to use coroutines, use them. you can simply throw and catch exceptions then.

Comment: Even if I compile with cxx_noexcept?

Comment: Well you know. If you want to remove the rote of error handling AND compile without exception support, you really MUST be using a librarified solution like the ideas mentioned above. But that just means that (a) you choose your own problems (b) you write your own integration so as to hide the impedance mismatch with 3rd party code

Comment: @sehe Can you turn that into an answer?

Comment: I don't see a fruitful way to do it. Unless, of course, you _can_ use coroutines with exceptions :)